# Display escaped html content properly when rendering in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have text like below which comes from JSON

```
&lt;div&gt;&lt;div&gt;All are lucky and contect is like
```

I want this to be displayed properly when rendered. How do i do this.

```
<p>{{bodydata}}</p>
```

Comment: what are you getting from above snippet ?"

Comment: `ng-bind-html` is what u need i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$sce (Strict Contextual Escaping)` for displaying HTML encoded characters

```js
function myCtrl($scope,$sce){
    $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml('&lt;div&gt;&lt;div&gt;All are lucky and contect is like');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <span ng-bind-html="html"></span>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Everything gets displayed as html content. Say i have bold tag, Content should come as bold.